# Looking for audio device driver for a Thinkpad R51 running Windows 7 Embedded Standard / Windows Thin PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, drivers, thinkpad

I've looked all over the internet for a legacy device driver that will work with a Thinkpad R51 running Windows 7 Embedded Standard / Windows Thin PC and I haven't found anything that works yet.

The `Device Manager` lists it as `Multimedia Audio Controller` and it's `Hardware Ids` look like this:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV24C5&SUBSYS_05541014&REV_01
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV24C5&SUBSYS_05541014
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV24C5&CC_040100
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV24C5&CC_0401
```

and the `Compatible Ids` look like this:

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_24C5&REV_01
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_24C5
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV24C5&CC_040100
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV24C5&CC_0401
PCI\VEN_8086
PCI\CC_040100
PCI\CC_0401
```

I've tried quite a few drivers, and tried to install them in compatibility mode to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Since that laptop uses AC'97 audio, did you try the Windows 7 Realtek AC'97 drivers?  If not, download them from [Realtek Here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=23&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) (if for some reason that doesn't work [start here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/)).  Don't forget though... as I stated at length in my answer to your Video driver question, you may still be disappointed.  You can't expect all hardware manufacturers to continue to support hardware after a decade of creating new and improved stuff.

Answer (score 0):

your audio chip appears to be an AD1981B, there appears to be a vista driver for it here:
http://www.x-drivers.com/catalog/drivers/sound_cards/companies/analog_devices/models/soundmax_ac97/397.html

if not, you can sometimes force drivers that don't seem to work at first in a number of ways.

sort of a rambling off the top of my head of things to try to force an old driver:

play with compatibility mode beyond the suggested settings, this has worked for me several times

if that doesn't work, try to fool the system. you can sometimes find drivers for a newer quite similar piece of hardware that works on the same chipset, perhaps pick apart the cab file a little and edit something here and there.